# java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class with Firebase Admin

Tags: java, eclipse, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a java program with Eclipse to take care of some things in my firebase realtime database. My code:

```
package server;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("src/server/something.json");

        // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).setDatabaseUrl("https://something.firebaseio.com").build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Status");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int status = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            System.out.println(status);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
        });

    }

}
```

My errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils.getDefaultTransport(Utils.java:51)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.<init>(FirebaseOptions.java:216)
    at server.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

My imports in the project:
firebase-admin-6.3.0.jar ; google-api-client-1.24.1.jar ; google-api-client-http-1.2.3-alpha.jar ; google-api-client-xml-1.2.3-alpha.jar ; google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.10.0.jar ; google-http-client-1.24.1.jar .
And a picture of the whole thing: https://image.ibb.co/kqNMne/whole.png

Comment: That error originates somewhere on one really long line.  Break it up into smaller statements to debug so you can get a line number that's more meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a version mismatch: something here was compiled against a version of a class that wasn't `final`, but now is. Downversion the dependencies you have locally to the Versions shown in the table at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/6.3.0 , then update each of the dependencies you have here one at a time until you know which one is a factor in the breakage--and open an Issue in the matching Github rep so they can fix this properly.

Comment: This. And also https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java , takes less time.